# Breakable, local table of contents with indented page numbers using etoc

Tags: formatting, page-breaking, etoc

I am trying to create a local, breakable table of contents using `etoc`. So far I had defined a new command called `\chaptertoc` where I placed the `\localtableofcontents` within a `parbox`. But now that the table of contents no longer fits on one page, there must be a page break. The desired result should look exactly like in my example (heading, upper and lower rules and indented page numbers on the right side), but there should be an automatic page break. This is prevented in the current version by the `parbox`. I have already tried various variants of replacing the `parbox`, among others with `adjustwidth`, `tcolorbox` or `mdframed`. With these I get the page break under control, but then the formatting is no longer correct.

Here is my example code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc, blindtext}

\newcommand{\chaptertoc}{%
\begingroup
\parbox[b]{0.96\textwidth}{
\etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{Heading of local toc\\ \vspace{-0.75em}\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}\vspace{-.5em}}{}%
\localtableofcontents
\vspace{-0.5em} 
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
}\\
\endgroup
}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{bla}
\blindtext[3]
\chaptertoc
\section{bla 1}
\subsection{blabla 1}
\subsection{blabla 2}
\subsection{blabla 3}
\subsection{blabla 4}
\section{bla 2}
\subsection{blabla 5}
\subsection{blabla 6}
\subsection{blabla 7}
\subsection{blabla 8}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

The desired result based on the example code should break like this ...

[image]

... but with the same formatting as above without the page break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting `\etocsettocstyle` an also putting the ToC page numbers in a `parbox` to get the desired format.

[image: T]

```
\etocsettocstyle{⟨before_toc⟩}{⟨after_toc⟩}
```

.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc, blindtext}

% *****************************************  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand*{\pagenumberbox}[1]{\parbox{6ex}{\centering #1}} % set the width of the page number box <<<<<
\RedeclareSectionCommands[tocpagenumberbox=\pagenumberbox]{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection}
% ***************************************** 

\newcommand{\chaptertoc}{%
        \etocsettocstyle{%
            \subsection*{Heading of local toc\\\vspace{-0.75em} \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace{-.5em}}
            }{\vspace{-0.5em}\noindent \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}%
        \localtableofcontents
}

\usepackage[margin=4cm, showframe]{geometry}%  % ONLY to set and show the margins

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \chapter{bla}
    \blindtext[3] 
    \chaptertoc 
    \section{bla 1}
    \blindtext[5] % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \subsection{blabla 1}       
    \subsection{blabla 2}       
    \subsection{blabla 3}
    \subsection{blabla 4}
    \section{bla 2}
    \subsection{blabla 5}
    \subsection{blabla 6}
    \subsection{blabla 7}
    \subsection{blabla 8}
\end{document}}
```

Without text above:

[image: z]

With `\blindtext[1]`  after `\chapter`

[image: o]

Answer (score 3):

Well, I worked on this, and I think I at least came close.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoc, blindtext}

\newenvironment{chaptertocwrapper}{\list{}{\setlength{\rightmargin}{1.5em}\setlength{\leftmargin}{0em}}\setlength{\baselineskip}{0ex}\setlength{\parskip}{0.8ex}\item\relax}
{\endlist}

\newcommand{\chaptertoc}{%
    \etocsettocstyle{%
       \subsection*{Heading of local toc\\ \vspace{-0.75em}\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}\vspace{-.5em}}%
    \relax\begin{chaptertocwrapper}\localtableofcontents\end{chaptertocwrapper}
\vspace{-1em}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{bla}
\blindtext[3]
\chaptertoc
\section{bla 1}
\subsection{blabla 1}
\subsection{blabla 2}
\subsection{blabla 3}
\subsection{blabla 4}
\section{bla 2}
\subsection{blabla 5}
\subsection{blabla 6}
\subsection{blabla 7}
\subsection{blabla 8}
\end{document}
```

[image: breakable toc]

Though I've noticed that weird things can happen if the vertical space on the page needs to stretch to reach a flush bottom, i.e., the spacing between the items can be different across the pages. Not sure how to fix that, but it may not matter for your actual use case (or maybe you won't mind).

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. The problem I have with the answer applied to my actual document is that there are chapters with long local tables of contents that need to have a page break, but also some with shorter ones that fit on one page only. These local tocs now have different spacing between the bottom line and the last entry. You can see this in the example if you change from `\blindtext[3]` to `\blindtext[1]`. Also, there is an error for chapters that have no text before the local table of contents. In the example this is reproducible by deleting `\blindtext[3]` completely.

Comment: I made an it that solves the second problem (I think) by adding `\leavevmode` to the second definition.) It partly solves the first problem for the bottom line, but there is still an issue with the top line (I think), which I can't quite figure out.