# Customizing TOC by combination use of etoc and tcolorbox gives unexpected output

Tags: table-of-contents, tcolorbox, etoc

In the following codes, I try to shipout a table of contents with two columns by `etoc` package. I put this toc into a `tcolorbox` because tcolorbox has the capacity of page-breakable. The real typeset however, is out of my desire. I don't know if this is problem from etoc or tcolorbox or my wrong use of them. Anyone can help that?

**Codes:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry,etoc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,width=5in]
  \etocmulticolstyle[2]{My Content}
  \tableofcontents
\end{tcolorbox}

\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}\section{sss}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A breakable tcb needs the breakable tcb library: `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}`. Do you want an effect like: `\begin{multicols}{2} \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]     \tableofcontents
\end{tcolorbox} \end{multicols}` ?

Comment: Thank you @Cicada for your suggestion. In my codes, `\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}` seems like containing the declearation of `\tcbuselibrary{breakable}`. I tried with`\begin{multicols}{2} \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]     \tableofcontents \end{tcolorbox} \end{multicols}` , and the effect is different from my desire.

Comment: A breakable `tcolorbox` can be used inside a multicolum environment, but a multicolum environment can only be used inside non-breakable `tcolorbox`. A not so good solution could be https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355586/1952

Comment: "different from my desire." is not a useful description. Say what you got, and what you wanted. People can not read your mind.

Comment: @David Carlisle I have been trying to upload a picture to illustrate what I want, but failed with `Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server`. I have to descript it with pure text: a breakable tcolorbox in which the TOC is displayed with two columns, that is to say, when the content of TOC is too large(as my codes show), it will be shipout in the same tcolorbox which occupies continuous pages.

Comment: @lyl yes image upload seems broken today for everyone

Comment: @Ignasi `etoc` uses `multicol` package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may serve as an MWE.

You want the tcolorbox from (2) to page-break like the tcolorbox from (1).

Is that correct?

(1). tcolorbox inside multicols

[image: option 1]

(2). multicols inside tcolorbox

[image: option 2]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry,etoc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}


%\newpage
%tcb:toc
%``Unbreakable tcolorboxes can be used without
%special care inside a multicols environment
%from the multicol package.
%Since version 3.10, a breakable tcolorbox
%detects, if it is used inside a multicols
%environment. But choosing break points
%for a breakable box cannot be done by the
%balancing routine of multicols. By default,
%boxes will break at maximum column
%height. To get pleasant results, use ...''


%Code adapted from:
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/639275/breakable-local-table-of-contents-with-indented-page-numbers-using-etoc
\newcommand{\chaptertoc}{%
        \etocsettocstyle{%
            \subsection*{Heading of local toc\\\vspace{-0.75em} \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace{-.5em}}
            }{\vspace{-0.5em}\noindent \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}%
            
(1). tcolorbox inside multicols           
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
breakable,
colback=brown!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title=My breakable box,
]
        \localtableofcontents
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{multicols}
}

\newpage
code
\chaptertoc

\newcommand{\revchaptertoc}{%
        \etocsettocstyle{%
            \subsection*{Heading of local toc\\\vspace{-0.75em} \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace{-.5em}}
            }{\vspace{-0.5em}\noindent \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[
breakable,
colback=brown!5!white,
colframe=red!75!black,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
title=My breakable box,
%break at=0.7\textheight,
%height fixed for=all,
]
\begin{multicols}{2}
%\begin{tcolorbox}[
%breakable,
%]
        \localtableofcontents
%\end{tcolorbox}
\end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\newpage
(2). multicols inside tcolorbox
\revchaptertoc


\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx
\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx\section{sss} xxx xxx xxx
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this solution.  `(2). multicols inside tcolorbox` is what I want because I'd like my toc of two columns is in the same frame. But when the contents of TOC is too large, parts of them will be outside of the box(as you say a tcolorbox loses breakable copacity with multicol enviroment in it),